# two docker machine, same web-app, two different IP, but needs to be sync

Tags: azure, docker

I have a scenario here where we are running docker machines on Microsoft Azure. One docker machine is for Hong Kong IP and the other is Singapore IP. Both docker machine contains same containers and its database is located with their own respective machines so it can be considered as their own local database which are Postgres database. Now our problem is.. How can we synchronize the data in their database of both machine? Did we do something wrong in our set-up? I am originally used to on using cloud service database like Postgres RDS on my previous projects but this kind of project set-up is new to me